# Scrolling of html element only working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, browser

If you run the below-mentioned code in Chrome, you get the desired result.  The inner container that wraps the two sections (when the browser window gets shrunk down) will display a vertical scrollbar.

However, if you do the same thing in Edge or Firefox, the browser just simply displays a vertical scrollbar over the whole page instead of on the given container element.

How can I get this to work consistently across at least the modern browsers -- Edge, Chrome and Firefox?

I've got the following:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header,
.footer,
.messagebar {
  display: flex;
  height: 4rem;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.container,
.section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.scrollable {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.section {
  margin: 10px 20px;
  flex-basis: 45%;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<body style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;flex-grow:1;height:100vh;">
  <div class="header">This is the header</div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="menu">This is the menu</div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="container scrollable" style="flex-direction: row;flex-wrap:wrap">
          <div class="section">
            <div>This is some content ...</div>
            <div>A table of data</div>
          </div>
          <div class="section">
            <div>This is further content ...</div>
            <div>A table of other data</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="messagebar">This is a message</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">This is the footer</div>
</body>
```

**Comment**

To see exactly what I'm talking about, run the code snippet and then choose the Full Page option.

Once you have the page displayed in its own window, you can play with resizing the window.  Resize horizontally should cause the right section to wrap below the  left section.  Resize vertically until you get a vertical scrollbar.  Do this in both Chrome and Firefox and you'll see the difference in the vertical scrollbar.

Comment: Not sure you understand.  I do want scrollbars -- I just want them on the element that I've specified in the middle of the page rather than scrolling the whole page.

Comment: You have to disable scrolling on the body and html.

Comment: If you mean `html, body { overflow: hidden }` all that does is ensures I get no scrollbars at all.

Comment: no it doesn't. You will still have scrollbars on children. You also have to set the html and body height to 100%

Comment: Have you tried it on the code I posted above?  Because all it does is hides all the page level scrollbars that were showing up.  The child scrollbars still don't show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Pogany over at [CssTricks](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/issue-with-scrollbar-works-in-chrome-not-in-firefox-or-edge/)!

The answer is to add the following to my `.scrollable` class

```
.scrollable{
   ...
   height: calc(100vh - 14rem);
}
```

That seems to work like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I think that a certain height is not defined. add specific height or max-height like below.

```
.scrollable {

    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    max-height: 92px;

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that defeats the purpose.  That inner container is supposed to take up all the available space -- hence the `display:flex; flex-grow: 1`